# Get the details of a file loaded with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

To load files in Spark I'm using these built-in methods:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> imageByteRDD = jsc.binaryFiles(SOURCE_PATH);
```

or

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> miao = jsc.wholeTextFiles(SOURCE_PATH);
```

I have a byte or a string representation of the files I'm picking up from the folder, which is stored in the value of the PairRDD. The key contains the filename.
How can I get the details of these files? Like

```
File miao = new File(path);
//this kind of details
String date = miao.getLastModified();
```

Should I reconvert them back to File and then read and then make of them another bytearray? Is there a faster process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom input format and pass that inputFormatClass to newApiHadoopFile method on SparkContext. This inputFormat will use a custom RecordReader, the custom recordReader will read the fileContent along with other file related information( ie. author, modifiedDate, etc...) . You need to write a custom Writable class to hold the file information and the fileContent read by record reader.

The full working code is given below. This code uses a custome input format class called **RichFileInputFormat**. The RichFileInputFormat is a wholeFileInputFormat which means there will be only one split per input file. Which further means that number of rdd partitions will be equal to number of input files. So if your input path contains 10 files then the resulting rdd will have 10 partitions in it regardless of the size of the input file(s).

This is how you can call this custom inputFormat from SparkContext to load the file:-

```
JavaPairRDD<Text, FileInfoWritable> rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(args[1],    RichFileInputFormat.class, Text.class,FileInfoWritable.class, new Configuration());
```

So your rdd key will be the filePath and value will a FileInfoWritable which contains both the file contents and other file related information.

Full working code is pasted below:-

1. Custom Input Format class

   ```
          package nk.stackoverflow.spark;

          import java.io.IOException;

          import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
          import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
          import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
          import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
          import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
          import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
          import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;

          public class RichFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, FileInfoWritable> {

           @Override
           public RecordReader<Text, FileInfoWritable> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
                   throws IOException, InterruptedException {

               return new RichFileRecordReader();
           }

           protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
               return false;
           }
          }
   ```

   1. Record reader

   package nk.stackoverflow.spark;

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;

   import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream; import
   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus; import
   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem; import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
   import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; import
   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit; import
   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader; import
   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext; import
   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit; import
   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil;

   public class RichFileRecordReader extends RecordReader<Text,
   FileInfoWritable> {     private String author;  private String
   createdDate;    private String owner;   private String lastModified;
       private String content;     private boolean processed;

       private Text key;   private Path path;  private FileSystem fs;

       public RichFileRecordReader() {

       }

       @Override   public void initialize(InputSplit split,
   TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
   {       // this.recordReader.initialize(split, context);        final
   FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;        final Path path =
   fileSplit.getPath();        this.fs =
   path.getFileSystem(SparkHadoopUtil.get().getConfigurationFromJobContext(context));
           final FileStatus stat = this.fs.getFileStatus(path);        this.path =
   path;       this.author = stat.getOwner();      this.createdDate =
   String.valueOf(stat.getModificationTime());         this.lastModified =
   String.valueOf(stat.getAccessTime());       this.key = new
   Text(path.toString());  }

       @Override   public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException,
   InterruptedException {      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           FSDataInputStream stream = null;        try {           if (!processed) {
                   int len = (int) this.fs.getFileStatus(this.path).getLen();
                   final byte[] data = new byte[len];

                   stream = this.fs.open(this.path);
                   int read = stream.read(data);
                   String content = new String(data, 0, read);
                   this.content = content;
                   processed = true;
                   return true;            }       } catch (IOException e) {           e.printStackTrace();            if (stream != null) {
                   try {
                       stream.close();
                   } catch (IOException ie) {
                       ie.printStackTrace();
                   }           }       }       return false;   }

       @Override   public Text getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
   InterruptedException {      // TODO Auto-generated method stub      return
   this.key;   }

       @Override   public FileInfoWritable getCurrentValue() throws
   IOException, InterruptedException {         // TODO Auto-generated method
   stub

           final FileInfoWritable fileInfo = new FileInfoWritable();
           fileInfo.setContent(this.content);
           fileInfo.setAuthor(this.author);
           fileInfo.setCreatedDate(this.createdDate);
           fileInfo.setOwner(this.owner);
           fileInfo.setPath(this.path.toString());         return fileInfo;    }

       @Override   public float getProgress() throws IOException,
   InterruptedException {      // TODO Auto-generated method stub      return
   processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;    }

       @Override   public void close() throws IOException {        // TODO
   Auto-generated method stub

       }

   }
   ```

   3. writable class

   package nk.stackoverflow.spark;

   ```
       import java.io.DataInput;
       import java.io.DataOutput;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.nio.charset.Charset;

       import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

       import com.google.common.base.Charsets;

       public class FileInfoWritable implements Writable {
           private final static Charset CHARSET = Charsets.UTF_8;
           private String createdDate;
           private String owner;
       //  private String lastModified;
           private String content;
           private String path;
           public FileInfoWritable() {

           }

           public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
               this.createdDate = readString(in);
               this.owner = readString(in);
       //      this.lastModified = readString(in);
               this.content = readString(in);
               this.path = readString(in);
           }

           public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
               writeString(createdDate, out);
               writeString(owner, out);
       //      writeString(lastModified, out);
               writeString(content, out);
               writeString(path, out);
           }

           private String readString(DataInput in) throws IOException {
               final int n = in.readInt();
               final byte[] content = new byte[n];
               in.readFully(content);
               return new String(content, CHARSET);
           }

           private void writeString(String str, DataOutput out) throws IOException {
               out.writeInt(str.length());
               out.write(str.getBytes(CHARSET));
           }

           public String getCreatedDate() {
               return createdDate;
           }

           public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
               this.createdDate = createdDate;
           }

           public String getAuthor() {
               return owner;
           }

           public void setAuthor(String author) {
               this.owner = author;
           }

           /*public String getLastModified() {
               return lastModified;
           }*/

           /*public void setLastModified(String lastModified) {
               this.lastModified = lastModified;
           }*/

           public String getOwner() {
               return owner;
           }

           public void setOwner(String owner) {
               this.owner = owner;
           }

           public String getContent() {
               return content;
           }

           public void setContent(String content) {
               this.content = content;
           }

           public String getPath() {
               return path;
           }

           public void setPath(String path) {
               this.path = path;
           }


       }
   ```

   4. Main class showing how to use

   package nk.stackoverflow.spark;

   ```
   import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration; import
   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; import org.apache.spark.SparkConf; import
   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD; import
   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext; import
   org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;

   import scala.Tuple2;

   public class CustomInputFormat {    public static void main(String[]
   args) {         
           SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();

           conf.setAppName(args[0]);   
           conf.setMaster("local[*]");         
           final String inputPath = args[1]; 
   JavaSparkContext sc = new
   JavaSparkContext(conf);         
   JavaPairRDD<Text, FileInfoWritable> rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(inputPath, RichFileInputFormat.class,
   Text.class,
                   FileInfoWritable.class, new Configuration());

           rdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<Text, FileInfoWritable>>() {

               public void call(Tuple2<Text, FileInfoWritable> t) throws
   Exception {
                   final Text filePath = t._1();
                   final String fileContent = t._2().getContent();
                   System.out.println("file " + filePath + " has contents= " + fileContent);           }       });

           sc.close();     } }
   ```

Comment: What a job! Does the newAPIHadoopFile method also work for local directories?

Comment: Yes this will work with local filesystem as well. Just give the absolute path of inputDirectory on local filesystem while calling the newApiHadoopFile method on SparkContext. This is how absolute path on local filesystem looks like-  file:///users/ram/inputDir

Answer (score 0):

Parse this RDD using map transformation. Inside your map function call a function that accepts a String (i.e you filename) and use this String to open and handle the file. So it is nothing more than a map RDD transformation which calls a function for every row of this RDD.

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid, actually, but thanks for the answer. And the reason being that this would go back to the driver, wouldn't it? What would I be using Spark for if every element I should just go back to simple Java. I guess I should make a PairRDD of my own.... ?

Comment: Yes. If you work in a cluster you could partition this RDD into many executors. This would fasten your program results. If you work locally then I'm afraid no. Since you need to read these files, which means Action, you would inevitably persist the files in driver's memory.

Comment: So if I am in a cluster environment, this map-> (load File(path) ) would be run anyway on the workers? Wouldn't it go back anyway to the driver to do it? I should indeed load files from hdfs and elaborate them according to their details.  
It still seems too elaborate: I load the files to load them a second time..,